# po command in Xcode does not generate output

Tags: ios, xcode, gdb, lldb

At some point during my work, Xcode's `po` and `p` commands stopped working. No matter what I enter, it doesn't generate output:

```
(gdb) po self
(gdb) po [self name]
(gdb) po [UITableView class]
(gdb) po @"Hello"
(gdb) p indexPath.row
(gdb) print indexPath.row
(gdb) po fjkldsjflksdjklwjfkljfkldsjflk
(gdb)
```

When I enter any of these commands, the command line just goes to the next line, where it prints the blue `(gdb)`, but no output.

I tried the following steps:

- Restart Xcode, restart my Macbook
- Tried while debugging in the simulator as well as on a iOS device
- Switched to LLDB and restarted
- Re-installed Xcode

The other debugging tools in Xcode seem to work okay: Breakpoints, step-by-step execution, the **Auto** variable examination window etc.

**Any ideas?**

**EDIT:** Doesn't work even after a re-install of Xcode.

Comment: Are you running in Release mode?

Comment: Nope it's Debug. As I said, all debugging tools are working fine.

Comment: guys you'd better check out both answers - I've struggle with each of them at different times

Comment: In my case, it was the device issue, after switching to the simulator, it worked again.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Silly me, I was in the 'Target Output' window instead of the 'Debugger Output' window.

[image]

Somehow I thought I checked the other console windows there, but apparently I didn't.

Comment: Just hit the same issue in XCode5. I truly believe that there is some shortcut which switch those tabs!

Comment: D'oh! Thanks (for the hint and not letting me feel super-stupid that I'm the only one doing the exact same thing…)

Comment: I have been fighting this issue for so long. Like 3 months have gone by and I've been trying to make do without lldb. Thank you for saving my sanity.

Comment: This answer is STILL correct after 9 years — thank you!

Answer (score 37):

[image]

I added filter in debugger which hid other logs. Removing the filter worked for me.